# Image delivered from s3 bucket returns 200 OK in profile but 403 forbidden in search results

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave

In one template (partial for search results) I have:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(result.avatar.thumb.url), result_path(result) %>
```

this evaluates to:

```
<img src="https://musicbookprod.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/thumb_LinkedIn.png?X-Amz-Expires=600&amp;X-Amz-Date=20151012T153320Z&amp;X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIQSLXZNRAL3H2O3A/20151012/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&amp;X-Amz-Signature=fbd73d10cf370765fd867a9f9cb65b100656f91a2edb4d68a358a32786f78115" alt="Aws4 request&amp;x amz signedheaders=host&amp;x amz signature=fbd73d10cf370765fd867a9f9cb65b100656f91a2edb4d68a358a32786f78115">
```

but the HTTP response code is 403 Forbidden

In another (artist profile page) I have:

```
<%= image_tag(@artist.avatar.thumb.url) %>
```

it evaluates to:

```
<img src="https://musicbookprod.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/thumb_LinkedIn.png?X-Amz-Expires=600&amp;X-Amz-Date=20151012T205409Z&amp;X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIQSLXZNRAL3H2O3A/20151012/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&amp;X-Amz-Signature=ef045a6a318bcae8cdb3e8d8e3b7718807ecb6cab48fa1cd708370fd58a0b584" alt="Aws4 request&amp;x amz signedheaders=host&amp;x amz signature=ef045a6a318bcae8cdb3e8d8e3b7718807ecb6cab48fa1cd708370fd58a0b584">
```

and returns a 200 OK rendering the image perfectly.

**UPDATE**

If I reset the Heroku database and recreate the artist profile then the avatar image is rendered in search the search results for the first fiew searches but afterwards returns forbidden.

Comment: I think you'll find the image is good for about 10 minutes after you "recreate the artist profile."  Is that right?  What is the body text accompanying the 403 Forbidden response?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes this is right. I seemed to have fixed it at the moment by deleting the image in the bucket and starting over, but what were you going to suggest?

Comment: Just from what you've shown, if the contents of `<img src ...>` don't change from page view to page view, then it looks as if you might be storing a signed URL with a 10 minute expiration time when you recreate the artist profile.